# Can't access scoped DbContext from root provider

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I get this error

> System.InvalidOperationException:
>   'Cannot resolve scoped service 'LC.Assets.API.ApiDbFullContext' from root provider.'

Registering `DbContextPool`:

```
services.AddDbContextPool<ApiDbFullContext>(o => o.UseSqlServer(connString));
```

`ExtensionDbHelper`:

```
public class ExtensionDBHelper : DisposableBase, IExtensionDBHelper
{
    public ExtensionDBHelper(IServiceProvider service)
    {
        IHttpContextAccessor http = service.GetRequiredService<IHttpContextAccessor>();
        IHostingEnvironment env = service.GetRequiredService<IHostingEnvironment>();
        IApiFullDbContext db = service.GetRequiredService<ApiDbFullContext>();

        this.DB = db;
        this.Helper = new ApiDbContextHelper(http, db, env);
        this.Worker = new ApiDbUnitOfWork(this.Helper);
    }

    public IApiFullDbContext DB { get; }
    public IApiDbContextHelper Helper { get; }
    public ApiDbUnitOfWork Worker { get; }
}
```

UseLCCors in IApplicationBuilderExtension:

```
public static IApplicationBuilder UseLCCors(this IApplicationBuilder builder, Action<LCCorsOptions> option)
{
    LCCorsOptions opt = new LCCorsOptions();
    option.Invoke(opt);

    IExtensionDBHelper helper = new ExtensionDBHelper(builder.ApplicationServices);
    ICorsOriginHub hub = GenericExpressions.CorsOriginHub(helper.Worker.GetRepo<CorsOriginHub>().DbSet).FirstOrDefault(h => h.Active && h.Version.Equals(opt.Version));

    if (hub == null)
    {
        throw new HubNotFoundException(opt.Version);
    }
    else if (hub.Outdated)
    {
        throw new IncludeHubOutdatedException(opt.Version);
    }

    foreach(ICorsOriginEntry entry in hub.Items.Where(itm => itm.Active))
    {
        builder.UseCors(options => options.WithOrigins(entry.Host).AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader());
    }

    return builder;
}
```

Comment: How do you get the services variable? Where do you call that line?

Comment: in an Extension function on ApplicationBuilder in Startup

Comment: Startup class has two methods so which one? It will be good to add a minimum example that reproduce the issue.

Comment: I've added more core now

Comment: The error message is basically saying you can't resolve a `DbContext` from the root context; in your `UseLCCors` method, have you tried wrapping the operations in a `using (builder.ApplicationServices.CreateScope())` and passing that scope's `ServiceProvider` property to the `ExtensionDBHelper`?

Answer (score 0):

this solved my issue:

Changing from *AddDbContextPool* to plain *AddDbContext*

Altering the code in ExtensionDBHelper to:

```
IApiFullDbContext db = service.CreateScope().ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ApiDbFullContext>();
```